# Where are the ----- ------ stored?

Tags: knowledge

Friday fun trivia puzzle time.

[image]

Goodluck all!

Comment: We should have some kind of notifications of when you post these kinds of puzzles, very cool puzzles!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Partial Answers:

Cyan:

> Rigel is the brightest
>
> > star
>
> in
>
> > Orion

Purple:

> The
>
> > Rebel
>
> leader is a princess (1977)
>
> > Star Wars

Red:

> > Napoleonic
>
> > Wars
>
> (1803 - 1815)

Peach:

> > Rebel without
>
> a
>
> > cause
>
> (1955)

Yellow:

> Avalanche Studios (2006)
>
> > Just Cause

Green:

> UK takeaways (2001-present)
>
> > [Just](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Eat)
>
> > [Eat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Eat)

Grey:

> > Love
>
> *Credit to [Gustavo Gabriel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64496/44845) for this word*
>   is overindulging
>
> > without
>
> ungirding

Blue:  *(Credit to [Gustavo Gabriel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64496/44845)) for this answer*

> > Endless
>
> > Love
>
> Diana Ross (1981)

### Final step:

I am currently assuming that the "true" answer is the answer to the question produced by filling in the blanks, and that the blanks are a 2-word anagram (5-6) of the first letters of the answer words:

> C E J N O R S W W **E L**<s>? ?</s>

This would probably (but not necessarily) mean that at least one of the 2 missing words

> begins with a vowel

With all the letters, the full question becomes:

> Where are the
>
> > Crown Jewels
>
> Stored?

To which the answer is

> [The Tower of London](https://www.hrp.org.uk/tower-of-london/history-and-stories/the-crown-jewels/)!

Filled in sheet:

> [image: Filled in image of question with answers]

Comment: Brilliant solve, absolutely spotbon.! Happy Friday!

Answer (score 6):

Shot in the dark for Grey and Blue:

Grey

> > Love
>
> is overindulging
>
> > without
>
> ungirding

Blue

> > Endless Love
>
> Diana Ross (1981)

*And as @Chronocidal said, one of them begins with a vowel*

Comment: That fits, *and* gives a valid anagram that makes a proper question too!  (+1)

Comment: Perfect solve to those clues. Happy Friday!